# Optimize array update and performance javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, oop

i'm trying to create a RPG game. But i guess der should be a lot of optimizations. One of the biggest problems, is the performance. I update an array with a for loop to set new blocks, but it takes way too long. I think also i should use OOP for a better performance, but how should it be?

Hope you can help me and sorry for my english :)

Javascript:

```
var keyCode = {};
var player = document.getElementsByClassName("player")[0];
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var iGrass = document.querySelectorAll(".interface > .grass")[0];
var iWater = document.querySelectorAll(".interface > .water")[0];
var iWall = document.querySelectorAll(".interface > .wall")[0];
var setEle = iWall;
var xPos = player.offsetWidth;
var yPos = player.offsetWidth;
var speed = 20;
var currentxPos;
var currentyPos;
var field = [];
field[0] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
field[1] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[2] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[3] = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[4] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, "g", "g", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[5] = [1, 0, 0, 0, "g", "g", "g", "g", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[6] = [1, 0, 0, 0, "g", "g", "g", "g", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[7] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, "g", "g", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[8] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[9] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "w", "w", "w", 1, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[10] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "w", "w", "w", 1, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[11] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[12] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[13] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[14] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[15] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
field[16] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

function setStage() {
  for (y = 0; y < field.length; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < field[y].length; x++) {
      if (field[y][x] == 1) {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<span class='wall'></span>";
      } else if (field[y][x] == "w") {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<span class='water'></span>";
      } else if (field[y][x] == "g") {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<span class='grass'></span>";
      } else {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<span></span>";
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('span').length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll("span")[i].style.width = player.offsetWidth + "px";
    document.querySelectorAll("span")[i].style.height = player.offsetWidth + "px";
  }
}
setStage();
div.style.width = field[0].length * player.offsetWidth + "px";

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keyCode[e.which || e.keyCode] = true;
  e.preventDefault();
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keyCode[e.which || e.keyCode] = false;
});

function playerMovement() {
  currentxPos = parseInt(xPos / player.offsetWidth);
  currentyPos = parseInt(yPos / player.offsetWidth);
  if (field[currentyPos][currentxPos] == "w") {
    speed = 1;
    player.style.transition = "0.4s all";
  } else {
    speed = 5;
    player.style.transition = "0.2s all";
  }
  /*Left*/
  if (keyCode[65] && xPos > 0) {
    if (field[currentyPos][currentxPos - 1] != 1) {
      xPos -= speed;
    } else {
      xPos = currentxPos * player.offsetWidth;
    }
  }
  /*Right*/
  if (keyCode[68] && xPos < div.offsetWidth - player.offsetWidth) {
    if (field[currentyPos][currentxPos + 1] != 1) {
      xPos += speed;
    } else {
      xPos = currentxPos * player.offsetWidth;
    }
  }
  /*Bottom*/
  if (keyCode[83]) {
    if (field[currentyPos + 1][currentxPos] != 1) {
      yPos += speed;
    } else {
      yPos = currentyPos * player.offsetWidth;
    }
  }
  /*Top*/
  if (keyCode[87] && yPos > 1) {
    if (field[currentyPos - 1][currentxPos] != 1) {
      yPos -= speed;
    } else {
      yPos = currentyPos * player.offsetWidth;
    }
  }
  /*Space*/
  if (keyCode[32]) {
    player.style.background = "#f00";
    if (field[currentyPos][currentxPos] == "g") {
      field[currentyPos][currentxPos] = 0;
      div.innerHTML = "";
      setStage();
    }
  } else {
    player.style.background = "#66f";
  }
  player.style.left = (currentxPos * player.offsetWidth) + "px";
  player.style.top = (currentyPos * player.offsetWidth) + "px";
}
iWall.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setEle = iWall;
});
iGrass.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setEle = iGrass;
});
iWater.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setEle = iWater;
});
div.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  var setXpos = parseInt(e.x / player.offsetWidth);
  var setYpos = parseInt(e.y / player.offsetWidth);
  if (setEle == iWall) {
    field[setYpos][setXpos] = 1;
  } else if (setEle == iGrass) {
    field[setYpos][setXpos] = "g";
  } else if (setEle == iWater) {
    field[setYpos][setXpos] = "w";
  } else {
    field[setYpos][setXpos] = 0;
  }
  div.innerHTML = "";
  setStage();
});
setInterval(function() {
  playerMovement();
}, 10);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="stage"></div>
<div class="player"></div>
<div class="interface">
  <span class="grass"></span>
  <span class="water"></span>
  <span class="wall"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {margin: 0;}

.player {
  border: 1px solid #66f;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #66f;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
  transform-origin: 50%;}
span {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  float: left;}
.wall {background: #e86;}
.water {background: #6af;}
.grass {background: #aea;}
.interface {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;}
```

*DEMO:
https://jsfiddle.net/Rakowu/nskzga7f/

Comment: OOP doesn't guarantee better performance.

Comment: The main problem is, that you update the whole grid every time, which causes the html parser to be busy. Thats why reactJS became so famous. So you may just listen to changes...

Comment: Yes, I tryied to fire only on click and on start of the document. But as I can see it still too performance consuming. How should i Optimize the steStage method? T.T

Comment: Alternatively you could use Canvas to create your game. That will save you from manipulating the DOM every time there is an action/change.

Comment: Yes, I know that canvas could be a solution. But I try to create it based on pure html and javascript :) I want to use this code as android app later. That's the reason i want avoid canvas and why i'm look for performance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try to replace only the selected block instead of parsing the whole content of player DIV. Just add id's to 's:

```
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<span class='wall' id='cell-"+y+"-"+x+"'></span>";
      } else if (field[y][x] == "w") {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<span class='water' id='cell-"+y+"-"+x+"'></span>";
      } else if (field[y][x] == "g") {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<span class='grass' id='cell-"+y+"-"+x+"'></span>";
      } else {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<span id='cell-"+y+"-"+x+"'></span>";
```

click on div:

```
div.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

   .....
   // div.innerHTML = "";
   // setStage();       
    document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute('id')).replaceWith(setEle.cloneNode())
});
```

Fix for click on space button

```
 if (keyCode[32]) {
    player.style.background = "#f00";
    if (field[currentyPos][currentxPos] == "g") {
      field[currentyPos][currentxPos] = 0;
      var selectedEl = document.getElementById('cell-'+currentyPos+'-'+currentxPos);
      var whiteSpace = document.createElement('span');
      whiteSpace.setAttribute('id', 'cell-' +currentyPos+'-'+currentxPos);
      whiteSpace.style.width = '20px';
      whiteSpace.style.height = '20px';
      selectedEl.replaceWith(whiteSpace);
    }
```

example here https://jsfiddle.net/nskzga7f/9/

Comment: Oh, that is a huge diference :D It's nearly perfekt. The only problem, by clicking on space the grid elements clones on a strange way. (Space is used to cut the "grass").

Comment: that way you may put data attribute for example `data-type="white-space"` and check its value before the `replaceWith` function and do what you need. Just the way I've added ID's

Comment: The only problem is that there is a callback on click, but i need to make them understand that on key press it should be replaced ^^ But now i have a good base for take it  further :D

Comment: I have edited my answer, maybe it will help you more.

Comment: Better but now you can only construct on grass :D
It only needed  type==='whiteSpace'
https://jsfiddle.net/Rakowu/nskzga7f/10/

Still having some bugs but now I can work with it and bug fix. Thank you Yordan :D